# ngChange not Triggered on ngModel change

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-change

UI bootstrap demonstrates a select dropdown using a button and a unordered list.  This is all fine and dandy, however, I am trying to get the same functionality as a select tag in HTML.  Functionality like selecting an option and changing the value of the model then firing a ng-change function.

I thought that an ngChange event fires when the ngModel attached to the input changes, however, this is not the case.  I have attached a plunker with my problem, which demonstrates the selection of the list item that changes the `user.group`'s `ng-model`, which should call the `ng-change="alert('blah')"`, but it doesnt.  Am I missing some kind of semantics with ngChange?

http://plnkr.co/edit/oZo7xGEVKvB0ntwiNFMp?p=info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are using ng-model directive on a button tag. That is not going to work since you can only use ng-model on html form input elements. Your button is not an input type. Check angularjs docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

> The ngModel directive binds an **input**,**select**, **textarea** (or custom form
>   control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is
>   created and exposed by this directive.

Comment: I read the docs, and must've overseen that.  Looks like a $watch is in order.  Thanks for fast response

Comment: $watch will indeed do it for you!

Answer (score 4):

As official docs said about `ngChange` directive:

> Evaluate the given expression when the user changes the input

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

So the directive has nothing with model changes, it deals with user interaction with form elemment.

More from the angular docs:

> It will not be evaluated:
>
> - if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has    not changed
> - if the input has continued to be invalid since the model will stay    null
> - if the model is changed programmatically and not by a    change to    the input value